# Como declarar tipo em uma função no Haskell?

Tags: haskell

> GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

Estou estudando Haskell nesse [site](http://haskell.tailorfontela.com.br/types-and-typeclasses).

Ele usa o exemplo de declaração de tipo em funções, porém ao tentar fazer o mesmo o ghci gera um erro.

```
addThree :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
```

> error: Variable not in scope: addThree :: Int ->
>   Int -> Int -> Int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para declarar o tipo de uma função você deve:

- definir a função e deixar que o GHC deduzir o tipo por conta própria, ou
- definir o tipo **e** a função no mesmo arquivo.

É provável que você tenha escrito só o tipo mas sem a definição, o que não é válido. Se quiser só anotar o tipo e definir a função só depois, você pode usar `undefined`:

```
addThree :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int 
addThree = undefined
```

Obs.: quando eu digo "só depois", quer dizer você voltar no arquivo, apagar `undefined` e colocar a definição desejada, já que em Haskell é impossível atribuir novos valores aos nomes já definidos, como acontece em linguagens imperativas.

Comment: Eu descobri qual era o erro, eu não posso definir função direto no Ghci, pelo menos não uma função recursiva e nem atribuir um tipo para função. Para os mesmos eu devo criar direto no arquivo .hs mesmo e compila-los.

Comment: @WesleyR.Guimarães Pelo contrário, você pode sim. Basta saber fazê-lo. Por exemplo: `fact n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * fact (n-1)` é recursiva e pode ser definida no GHCi. Se quiser usar casamento de padrões, você deve usar `:{` e `:}`, ou `let { linha um; linha 2; ... }`, para definir funções de mais de uma linha.

Comment: Interessante, muito obrigado, era isso que queria saber.